# Observed and estimated proportions differ with binomial GLM - which to present?

Tags: estimation, generalized-linear-model

Using the `predict()` command in R, I have been able to calculate estimates (`av2`) and se-intervals (upper, lower)for my data below. The calculated proportion (`av2`) is different from the observed proportion (`av1`) - so 1. I'm not sure why this is? When writing up the experiment which should I quote and graph? Data and working are below.

```
A<-c(10,10,10,10,10,10,19,19,19,19,19,19)
B<-c("0","1","2","0","1","2","0","1","2","0","1","2")
C<-c("-ve","-ve","-ve","+ve","+ve","+ve","-ve","-ve","-ve","+ve","+ve","+ve")
Dead<-c(1,1,27,0,6,18,2,10,23,0,14,21)
Alive<-c(29,32,2,22,19,4,28,22,3,20,11,0)
Total<-Dead+Alive
gaf<-data.frame(A,B,C,Dead,Alive,Total)

mod2<-glm(cbind(Dead,Alive)~A+B+C, family=binomial)

p<-predict(mod2,newdata=gaf,se.fit=TRUE)
up<-with(p,fit+se.fit)
low<-with(p,fit-se.fit)
invLink<-family(mod2)$linkinv
av2<-with(p,invLink(fit))
upr<-invLink(up)
lwr<-invLink(low) 
av1<-Dead/Total

round(av1, digits=2)
# 0.03 0.03 0.93 0.00 0.24 0.82 0.07 0.31 0.88 0.00 0.56 1.00 # observed 

round(av2, digits=2) 
# 0.01 0.11 0.83 0.02 0.19 0.90 0.03 0.33 0.95 0.07 0.49 0.97 # estimate 

round(upr, digits=2) 
# 0.02 0.15 0.88 0.03 0.26 0.94 0.06 0.40 0.97 0.12 0.57 0.98 # upper and lower se

round(lwr, digits=2)
# 0.00 0.08 0.76 0.01 0.14 0.86 0.02 0.26 0.92 0.04 0.41 0.96
```

Answer (score 3):

*Of course* the predicted values differ from the observed ones: you fitted a model that imposes all kinds of restrictions, which the original data does not have to follow. Specifically, your model assumes that there is no interaction between the predictors: the effect of variable A is the same regardless of the value of B and C, and similarly of the other variables.

If you do want a perfect fit, you have to fit a saturated model with all interaction terms:

```
mod3 <- glm(cbind(Dead,Alive)~A*B*C, family=binomial, data=gaf)
round(predict(mod3, type="response"), 2)
 #0.03 0.03 0.93 0.00 0.24 0.82 0.07 0.31 0.88 0.00 0.56 1.00
```

On the other hand, doing this completely obliterates the whole point of modeling - you could have calculated the standard error for each row separately. Try running the model on, say, the first row (`glm(cbind(Dead,Alive)~1, family=binomial,data=gaf[1,])`) - you will get exactly the same predicted value and standard error as with the saturated model.

**Edit**

In a paper, we often report observed proportion and the fitted proportion with confidence intervals. If the observed proportion is nowhere near the fitted proportion, then you have a bad model, which you should not be reporting.

Comment: OK thanks, but which would you include in a paper? It seems the norm to present observed data, but is this the correct thing to do if your model is testing something else? Also, when i produce the mod3, as you suggested, the standard errors for the estimates where there are 0% or 100% deaths are very large (they pretty much span from 0%-100%) - this seems odd to me, and is there any way around this? Finally, when I try running a model with 1 row I just get an error

Comment: I made edits to clarify how to run the model with only one row (you can't have any predictors), and added a comment about reporting.